# Instagram API (JSON + PHP): show entries starting from X and not from 0

Tags: php, json, api, instagram

:)
This is the code I'm using right now to pull my entries from Instagram:

```
        <?php
        setlocale(LC_TIME, 'it_IT');
        function get_instagram($tag=bombacarta,$count=10,$width=612,$height=612){
            $url = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/'.$tag.'/media/recent/?access_token=13137.f59def8.1a759775695548999504c219ce7b2ecf&count='.$count;
            // Also Perhaps you should cache the results as the instagram API is slow
            $cache = './wp-content/themes/raymond-31/instagram_json/'.sha1($url).'.json';
            if(file_exists($cache) && filemtime($cache) > time() - 500){
                // If a cache file exists, and it is newer than 1 hour, use it
                $jsonData = json_decode(file_get_contents($cache));
            } else {
                $jsonData = json_decode((file_get_contents($url)));
                file_put_contents($cache,json_encode($jsonData));
            }
            $result = '<div style="border-top:1px solid #ddd">'.PHP_EOL;
            foreach ($jsonData->data as $key=>$value) {
                $location = (!empty($value->location->name))?'presso '.$value->location->name:null;
                $result .= "\t".'<em>'.htmlentities($value->caption->text, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8").'</em><br /><img src="'.$value->images->standard_resolution->url.'" alt="'.htmlentities($value->caption->text, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8").'" width="'.$width.'" height="'.$height.'" /><br /><div class="postinfo">Scattata da '.$value->caption->from->full_name.' il '.htmlentities(gmstrftime('%e %B %Y alle %R', $value->caption->created_time + 7200)).' '.htmlentities($location).'</div><br />'.PHP_EOL;
            }
            $result .= '</div>'.PHP_EOL;
            return $result;
        }
        echo get_instagram();
        ?>
```

I'd love to have that after 5 entries I can show the others as thumbnails. So I'd like to have 5 enties in standard_resolution and the other.. 10..? 20..? (dunno) as a clickable thumbnail.

Of course I can copy/paste the code again replacing standard_resolution with thumbnail_resolution but how can I specify that I'd like to start from (say) entry 5 instead that entry 0 (to avoid to repeat the same 5 images again before the other ones)? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
  function get_instagram($tag=bombacarta,$count=10,$width=612,$height=612){
            $url = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/'.$tag.'/media/recent/?access_token=13137.f59def8.1a759775695548999504c219ce7b2ecf&count='.$count;
            // Also Perhaps you should cache the results as the instagram API is slow
            $cache = './wp-content/themes/raymond-31/instagram_json/'.sha1($url).'.json';
            if(file_exists($cache) && filemtime($cache) > time() - 500){
                // If a cache file exists, and it is newer than 1 hour, use it
                $jsonData = json_decode(file_get_contents($cache));
            } else {
                $jsonData = json_decode((file_get_contents($url)));
                file_put_contents($cache,json_encode($jsonData));
            }
            $result = '<div style="border-top:1px solid #ddd">'.PHP_EOL;
            $ic=0;
            foreach ($jsonData->data as $key=>$value) {
                $location = (!empty($value->location->name))?'presso '.$value->location->name:null;
if($ic>=5){$res_c=thumbnail_resolution; $x_data="TESTT";}else{$res_c=standard_resolution;$x_data='Scattata da '.$value->caption->from->full_name.' il '.htmlentities(gmstrftime('%e %B %Y alle %R', $value->caption->created_time + 7200)).' '.htmlentities($location);}
$ic++;
                $result .= "\t".'<em>'.htmlentities($value->caption->text, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8").'</em><br /><img src="'.$value->images->$res_c->url.'" alt="'.htmlentities($value->caption->text, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8").'" width="'.$width.'" height="'.$height.'" /><br /><div class="postinfo">'.$x_data.'</div><br />'.PHP_EOL;
            }
            $result .= '</div>'.PHP_EOL;
            return $result;
        }
```

Comment: First of all, thanks for your reply!! :D
Uhm.. here's the result: http://bombacarta.com/bombafoto-prova/
The 6th entry is still displayed as the others..

Comment: You've got some caching going on here? That could be the issue.

Comment: Now something has changed, the problem is that the 6th entry has an emtpy <img src="">.. :)

Comment: On the 6th pic, do you just need to adjust the `$width` and `$height`? Or do you also need to change `$image->standard_resolution` to `$image->thumbnail_resolution`?

Comment: For the entries >5 I'd like to change the src to $image->thumbnail_resolution. :)

Comment: Try the edit. It should do what you need now, but if it doesn't, test all of them with `thumbnail_resolution`.

Comment: Can I ask you another thing (if you want).. would it be difficult to have a different text (say.. "test") for the entries >5 (I mean the text inside <div class="postinfo"> ) ? :)

Comment: To change the div class name? (like:  `<div class="test">`) or to change the text inside the div (like:  `<div class="postinfo">test`)?

Comment: Thanks!! :)
The only question left is how do I put '.$value->caption->from->full_name.' (for example) inside $x_data="".

I tried with:
    if($ic>=5){$res_c=thumbnail;$x_data="thumbnail text";}else{$res_c=standard_resolution;$x_data="Scattata da '.$value->caption->from->full_name.'";}

But I got an error:
Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

How do I "include" '.$value->caption->from->full_name.' inside $x_data="" without errors?

Thanks!! :))

Comment: My bad. Fixed it. Try it now xD

Comment: I don't know how to do that.. I tried to vote up but I think I can't (requires up to 15 reputation..). I have only 7. :(
I'm really sorry!

Comment: Lol. :D Actually I haven't still figured out how this reputation thing works.. :P